# Rails - How should mulitple checkboxes be combined as one value in a database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

As part of an application I'm building, I need to store the days on which some action needs to happen.

Currently I have this stored in a 7-digit bit-string, with each digit corresponding to one day of the week. A value of 1 for any day means the action **should** happen that day, a value of 0 means it **should not**.

Ex. String *0101110* means the action should run on Tuesday, Thursday, Friday and Saturday every week.

In my form, I have seven checkboxes set up, one for each name.

How would I go about merging these seven Boolean results into the one bitstring, such that I can save it in the database?

Would you do this in the view, or the model?

I've done some thinking myself, and one option (in the view) could be to set up a hidden field in the form that is the result of joining/concatenating the seven Booleans from the checkboxes. Then the checkboxes' values could be discarded on submit. I'm just not quite sure how to do this in rails.

Another option could be to handle the merging in the model. Again - not quite sure what to do.

Any help appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the checkbox values for the weekdays as virtual attributes on your model, and concatenate them on a `before_save` hook. In your model:

```
attr_writer :mon, :tue, :wed, :thu, :fri, :sat, :sun
before_save :set_weekdays

private

def set_weekdays
  self.weekdays = bitstr(@mon) + bitstr(@tue) + bitstr(@wed) # etc
end

def bitstr(bool)
  bool ? "1" : "0"
end
```

Make sure to permit `mon` and co as strong parameters for the model in Rails 4. You might also want to define getters for these attributes that would get filled from the bitstring, so that the form could render with the correct checkboxes pre-selected on edits.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the week column is `week`
You can make the week column of `type: text` and add this to your model
   `serialize :week` : this helps to save an array in the column

next, create a class Week, where week.rb:

```
class Week
  include ActiveModel::Model

  attr_accessor :id, :name
  DAYS = [
      {id: 1, "day" => "monday"},
      {id: 2, "day" => "tuesday"},
      ...

  ]

  def self.days
    DAYS.map {|d| self.new(
                          id: d[:id],
                          name: d[:day]
    )}
  end
end
```

and then, you can call the checkboxes from the view as follow:

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes(:week, Week.days, :id, :name, include_hidden: false) do |b| %>
            <%= b.check_box(class: "check_box") %>  <%= b.object.name %>
 <% end %>
```

lastly, dont forget to make the week atribute accesible from the controller. In rails 4, this will be:

```
params.require(:user).permit(week: [])
```

Hope this helps you?